# When do you choose a different package directory than force-app?

Tags: salesforcedx

So - maybe this is a stupid question. But I'm so confused by the package directory name that is by default just `force-app`, correct? So why would you ever change this? What are the implications of changing vs. not changing it? As I'm in the middle of a couple of migration this would be a great moment to get this straight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name of the folder containing the package source code is arbitrary. `force-app` is the default value.

```
sfdx help force:project:create
...
   -p, --defaultpackagedir=defaultpackagedir                                         [default: force-app] default package directory name
```

If you are managing multiple apps in the same repository it would make sense to use a different name. Package directories are specified in the generated `sfdx-project.json` file.

Comment: +1 Stated differently, for any *real* project, it probably should not be "force-app", but "my-cool-app" or "system-core" or whatever.

Comment: That is precisely my question as it is a very big project I'm moving and "force-app" seems incredibly non-descriptive. So I guess this goes more in the direction of naming it after e.g. the repository, yes?